# SQL query to join one to many relation with many to many relation

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have the following structure

```
COFFEE         ORDER_ITEMS        ORDERS           USERS  
------         -----------        ------           -----
id             order_id           id               id
name           coffee_id          user_id          email
```

There is a many to many relation between orders and coffees. And a one to many relation between users and orders. I would like to know what coffees a user has ordered.

I have a query to retrieve the orders per user:

```
SELECT users.id as USERID, orders.id as ORDERID
FROM users
INNER JOIN orders on users.id = orders.user_id
```

As an example this gives me:

```
userid  orderid
1       1
1       2
2       3   
4       4
```

I have a query to retrieve the coffees that belong to an order:

```
SELECT orders.id, coffees.name
FROM orders, coffees, order_coffees
WHERE coffees.id = order_coffees.coffee_id
AND orders.id = order_coffees.order_id
```

As an example, this gives me:

```
orderid coffeename
1       Coffee A
1       Coffee B
2       Coffee A
2       Coffee C
```

I would like to get the following:

```
userid  orderid coffeename
1       1       Coffee A
1       1       Coffee B
1       2       Coffee A
2       3       Coffee C    
4       4       NULL
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use the modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and **easier to convert to outer join** if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should join all 4 tables starting from the table `users` and use `INNER` joins if you want results only for the users who have ordered a coffee at least once, or `LEFT` joins if you want results for all users, even the ones who have never placed and order.

Use proper joins with `ON` clauses and aliases for the tables to make the code more readable:

```
SELECT u.id userid, 
       o.id orderid,
       c.name coffeename
FROM users u
INNER JOIN orders o ON o.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN order_items oi ON oi.order_id = o.id
INNER JOIN coffees c ON c.id = oi.coffee_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

data sheet
1.main order(master_list)
3.Order Details(booking)
3.coffee Meals(shop)
4.user information(user)

```
SELECT * FROM `booking` as a 
inner join `master_list` as b on a.`mas_id`=b.`mas_id` 
inner join `shop` as c on a.`shop_id`=c.`shop_id`
inner join `user` as d on b.`user_id`=d.`user_id`
```

I don't know if it helps you try it